# Embed a PDF document from server in HTML page using Java Servlet /JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, pdf, servlets

I am currently able to serve up files from my server directory to the HTML front end. However, I am currently only able to have these files downloaded, or opened fully on the page. What I want to do is embed them within my webpage.

I can easily do this if the files are stored in the web directory but using the embed tag.

Currently I am doing something along the lines of this:

Servlet file :

```
@MultipartConfig
@WebServlet
public class FileServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        File file = new File("filePath");
        String mimeType = getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName());
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", mimeType);
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "embed; filename=\"fileName.pdf\""); 
        Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
     }
}
```

JSP :

```
<form action="getFile" method="post" id="fileForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="fileName" value="<%out.print(cvKey);%>/<%out.print(name);%>.pdf"/>
</form>
```

Where the form is automatically submitted on page load.

I've been trying to set the source of the embedded tag to the output of the Servlet file, but nothing I have tried works in the way I want it to.

Any help would be amazing!!

UPDATE:

I've tried a few more things; including using an iframe like :

```
<iframe name="frame" width="500" height="300"></iframe>
```

And then setting the target of the form to the name of that frame. This still doesn't work and I just get an empty frame and the file gets downloaded :/.

EDIT :

Tried using the embed tag with a path directly to the file unsuccessfully :

My code :

```
<embed id="embeddedPDF" src="/home/user/resources/candidate.pdf" width="1000" height="1000" type='application/pdf'></embed>
```

And the error :

```
The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

Comment: I hope you have already tried using embed tag to display a file without the form submission logic?

Comment: Yeah I've tried that, but that won't let me access the files from the server; only from the web directory.

Comment: I am not sure if I am perfectly clear with this,so from the response u send back,there would be a page with some content+a section with the embedded pdf.Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. But as of now the pdf that I want to be embedded in a section of the page is either being displayed full screen or downloaded.

Comment: That is because ur sending back response mime type as file.You can send  response as text and send file path as an attribute which can be used as source path for embedding file in page.

Comment: Would that work accessing the server side file from the web front end though? From within the html I already know where the file is stored, as I tell the servlet where to go and look. I'd previously tried to point the source of file downloads and embeds to the server file store and it can't see it.

Comment: So static files on the server can be directly access through some relative URL,until restricted by some permissions.Try sending relative path of file as attribute and access on page within embed tag

Comment: In my experience static server side files can't be passed directly to the web front end. I've just tried what you said and it hasn't been able to find the file in the location I specified, and the file is definitely there.

I've edited my question with what I tried.

Comment: Try using a absolute URL to access the file path

Comment: I've just tried an absolute path by doing:

/home/simon/resources/candidateInfo/candidate.pdf

This doesn't work, it says it can't find the file.